# Newly-upgraded 13.04 hanging randomly?

Tags: 13.04

I just upgraded to 13.04 on both my desktop and my laptop, but only my desktop is having this problem. It spontaneously hangs - I could be doing anything: trying to pull up the launcher, switching windows, clicking a link, typing an email - and becomes totally unresponsive (though the cursor moves) for anywhere from two to ten minutes. Sometimes it unfreezes and then freezes again a second later, sometimes it clears right up and performs fine for the next half-hour.

I've also seen a couple of errors - 'System program problem detected,' and an error related to (I *think*) usr/bin/Xorg that I haven't been able to replicate yet. These errors don't coincide with the hanging as far as timing goes.

I'm still pretty new to Ubuntu, so I'm learning my way around yet, but I'm picking up fast on the basics.

Comment: If you run `top` in a terminal window, you'll see what's running and what resources it's taking up second by second. It might tell you whats tying everything up if you keep it uncovered while you work so that you can see it whenever this freeze happens. (`top` is one of my favorite commands to track down problems.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the Exact Same problem, `Upgrade RAM` and `Enable Swap`
if you have 4GB RAM i think very good and enough, make sure Swap is enabled
for more instructions about making swap please comment to me, but first make sure it's off or on